# git branch manager ui?

Tags: git

Is there any git UI for managing just git branches, hidding commits? All currently available git clients show big log report with all commits in branches, so I might lost the focus of a branch that is not on screen, due to many commits that happened recently.

I want to be able to 'minimize' or to 'collapse' all commits into single dot (bigger dot - more commits are collapsed) or line (thicker line - more commits) and to visualize only branches that then can be manipulated. So, again, it is like SmartGit log view, but with collapsed commits of branch, so I can quickly see just the git branch tree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a nice option that you can use with `gitk` called `--simplify-by-decoration` which only displays commits that are pointed to by branches or tags.  I've given a "before and after" example below.  Any tool that takes options understood by `git rev-list` such as `git log`, `gitk` and many others can take this parameter.

### Before

`gitk --all`

[image: gitk --all]

### After

`gitk --all --simplify-by-decoration`

[image: gitk --all --simplify-by-decoration]